# How to load dicom file in angular 7 project using cornerstone

Tags: javascript, angular, dicom

I want to load a dicom file which I have put in my virtual directory of IIS, I am using cornestone-wado-image-loader to achieve the same. but I am getting below error:

> "TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.
>       at _global.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) [as readAsArrayBuffer] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4589:60)
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:138552:35977
>       at new ZoneAwarePromise (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:4111:29)
>       at Ie (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:138552:35867)
>       at Object.load (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:138552:31691)
>       at Ae (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:138552:37680)
>       at loadImageFromImageLoader (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:96174:25)
>       at Object.loadAndCacheImage (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:96237:21)
>       at ViewImageComponent.ngAfterViewInit (http://localhost:4200/main.js:777:65)
>       at callProviderLifecycles (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:66735:18)"

Code which I have written for the same is:

```js
import {Component,OnInit,Input,ElementRef,ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from "@angular/core";
import cornerstone from "cornerstone-core";
import cornerstoneMath from "cornerstone-math";
import cornerstoneTools from "cornerstone-tools";
import Hammer from "hammerjs";
import cornerstoneWebImageLoader from "cornerstone-web-image-loader";
import cornerstoneWADOImageLoader from "cornerstone-wado-image-loader";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { switchMap, map } from "rxjs/operators";
import dicomParser from "dicom-parser";

var config = {
   maxWebWorkers: navigator.hardwareConcurrency || 1,
   startWebWorkersOnDemand: true,
};

cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.webWorkerManager.initialize(config);

@Component({
  selector: "app-view-image",
  templateUrl: "./view-image.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./view-image.component.css"]
})
export class ViewImageComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.external.cornerstone = cornerstone;
    cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.external.dicomParser = dicomParser;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    const element = document.querySelector(".image-canvas");

    const DCMPath = "http://localhost/images/Abdomen.Dcm";
    cornerstone.enable(element);

    cornerstone.loadAndCacheImage("dicomfile:" + DCMPath).then(imageData => {
      console.log(imageData);
      cornerstone.displayImage(element, imageData);
    }).catch( error => { console.error(error) });

    cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.wadouri.fileManager.remove(imageID);
  }
 
}
```

My package.json has below version of dependencies:

> "cornerstone-core": "^2.3.0",
>       "cornerstone-math": "^0.1.8",
>       "cornerstone-tools": "^4.8.0",
>       "cornerstone-wado-image-loader": "^2.2.4",
>       "cornerstone-web-image-loader": "^2.1.1",
>       "dicom-parser": "^1.8.3",
>       "file-system": "^2.2.2",
>       "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
>       "pako": "^1.0.10",

I tried for loading jpg/png image using cornerstone-web-image-loader and it worked perfectly, but when I changed to wado image loader I couldn't get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made below two changes to make it work for me:
 1. config variable change, I missed to add codecsPath and webWorkerPaths

```
var config = {
    webWorkerPath: '/assets/cornerstone/webworkers/cornerstoneWADOImageLoaderWebWorker.js',
    taskConfiguration: {
        'decodeTask': {
            codecsPath: '/assets/cornerstone/codecs/cornerstoneWADOImageLoaderCodecs.js'
        }
    }
}
```

2. changed the loader from "dicomfile" to "wadouri"

```
cornerstone.loadAndCacheImage("wadouri:" + DCMPath).then(imageData => {
      console.log(imageData);
      cornerstone.displayImage(element, imageData);
    }).catch( error => { console.error(error) });
```